# Passing data inside the application via services

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a web app that has rows of data which has a column called `active`. If a row is inactive the row is still presented to the user.

The client wants to have a `localStorage` toggle option to hide inactive rows from the view. Since all of my logic happens in the controller using the `localStorage` to filter html rows just doesn't seem proper. (Hiding elements with javascript vs simply filtering the data at the controller level).

If I cannot add a new column in the database for a "hide inactive items" feature--what would be the best solution to add a `toggle inactive items` in the entire application?

I was thinking of creating a claim:

`new Claim(ClaimTypes.UserData, "true", ClaimValueTypes.Boolean), // Hide inactive rows`

And later in the application:

```
internal static bool showInactiveRows(ClaimsPrincipal user)
{
    var showInactive = true; // Default hide inactive rows
    var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)user.Identity;
    if (identity != null)
    {
        // Get claim containing our setting
        var _showInactiveRows = identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.UserData);

        if (_showInactiveRows != null)
            // Set the session value to the model
            showInactive = bool.Parse(_showInactiveRows.Value);

    }
    return showInactive;
}

internal static async void setHideInactiveRows(ClaimsPrincipal user, bool hideInactiveRows)
{
    var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)user.Identity;
    if (identity != null)
    {
        // Get claim containing our setting
        var _showInactiveRows = identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.UserData);

        identity.RemoveClaim(_showInactiveRows);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.UserData, hideInactiveRows.ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Boolean));

        /*if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User)) // Need to call this to refresh claims without logging out
        {
            var user = await UserManager.GetUserAsync(User);
            await SignInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user);
        }*/

    }
}
```

Then when I'm grabbing data:

```
var hideInactiveRows = UserClaims.showInactiveRows(User);

if(hideInactiveRows)
{
    FarmList = await _context.Farms
        .Where(i => i.Active == hideInactiveRows) // Active = true show only active rows
        .OrderBy(g => g.Name)
        .ToListAsync();
} else {
     FarmList = await _context.Farms
        .OrderBy(g => g.Name)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

However this too doesn't seem right to me.

Is there a better way to update and pass data inside the application on a per user basis?

Comment: i do curious, is the "hide inactive item" thing need to be stored across different browser instance for the same user? if not, a query string as a flag will definitely easier. otherwise, just go with claims/session.

Comment: Just the current session is good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who needs a solution in the future I tried the query param checking in the OnGet() method but this was taking too long as I have to modify 50 pages.

The solution I came up with is to simply just create a Singleton Service:

```
public interface IUserMemStorage
{
    // Using concurrent dictionary as it's thread safe
    ConcurrentDictionary<int, string> UserHideInactiveRowStore { get; set; }
        
    // Create other tmp storages here
}

// Note: Only register this interface as a singleton
// I created a new interface to explicitly mention singleton
public interface IUserMemStorageSingleton : IUserMemStorage { }

public class UserMemStorage : IUserMemStorageSingleton
{
    public UserMemStorage()
    {
        UserHideInactiveRowStore = new();
    }

    public ConcurrentDictionary<int, string> UserHideInactiveRowStore { get; set; }
}
```

then later register the service in the `Startup.cs`.

Now on the pages I need this on I can simply use the dependency injection container and check if I should show/hide the results based on the `userId`. No need to modify any backlinks or different navigation pages as the `bool` is stored in the thread safe dictionary. :)